# Cannot Build or Archive an Xcode project that Runs Fine

Tags: swift, xcode6

When I run my project, the app opens and works just as it should. When I try to archive it to distribute to beta testers I get the following error:

[image]

This error doesn't show up when I run the project, only when I archive it and build it. I am using Xcode 6 Beta 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work for me with Xcode 6 Beta 5.

`sender.tag` may be a different type than 1.

`1` should be `Int`. `sender.tag` may be `UInt`. *Beta 2* maybe didn't had the minus operator (a - b) for these 2 different types (a: UInt and b: Int) when using the archive feature.

Comment: Okay so your recommending I update to Xcode 6 Beta 5